# How can I simulate pointers without using them?

Tags: c#, c, data-structures, pointers

I've got a C# code that runs on Azure and is web enabled so it should be safe. That means I can't use pointers.

I've got this problem - My Data structure is a SortedList where each node is an object X. Each object X includes an array where each cell is another SortedList of object Y. objects of type X and Y have distinct IDs (so they are searchable of course).

Now, I need a way to get directly to a Y object, without searching it through X objects and then Y objects. (It could be millions on objects)

In C/C++ I'd use a list of Y object IDs with pointers to the actual object. Such way I'd search only once for the object.

Any ideas how this could be accomplished in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason there are no pointers in C# is *almost everything is a pointer*. If you say `MyClass p = a[i];`, `p` is a pointer. `a` is an array of pointers, and both `a[i]` and `p` are pointing at the same object. What you can't do is *pointer arithmetic*.

Comment: ohh... so I CAN have a list of pointers. Just declare them as objects (without initializing them)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It seems that my objects qualify to be of reference type, i.e - a kind of pointer :)

Comment: People often talk about reference types vs value types in .NET. Nobody ever seems to mention the mysterious third type - References! Because they are in fact pointers and pointers scare people...

Comment: If you simulate pointers, you will also simulate the associated problems. Pointers are essentially means of indirection. It is in the nature of indirection that it can lead you nowhere, unless you take extra steps (check every indirect reference if it's still valid).

To put it differently: simulating pointers doesn't give you any essential security benefits over simply using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use instances in C# as you would in your C++ solution, but without the `->` C++ pointer deref. All things that refer to an instance of a class type in .NET are object references, which are actually pointers. If you construct an instance of a type in C# and assign it to a variable and an array element and pass it as an argument, all of those are pointers to the same object data in memory.

No need to simulate pointers in C#. Everything already is a pointer.

Comment: Thanks :) That's the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

well you could try hashing, there is the [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)
class. If everything is in a sorted list though you can use binary search which even with millions of records wont take that long.

Rereading your explanation of your data structure i have this question. what is the point of object X storing Object Y if your initial plan is to store a list of all Y's separately anyway? why cant you store a sorted list of X where each X contains a sorted list of the ids of associated Y objects, and you have a separate sorted list of Y objects? if its possible to search Y without knowing its related X then you are creating a bad data structure to hold you objects. Or you could create a database and use SQL to grab what you need when you need it, which if you have millions of records is probably a good way to go.

Comment: Well, the problem with a HashTable is the need to make it bigger after several operations (mostly A LOT operations) - my data is highly dynamic and the operation of creating a new HashTable every so and then can result in really bad results.

About SQL - all the data is stored in SQL. The data structure is for the cache because I must have real-time data querying. SQL just won't do what I need.

I could reverse it as you say - store all Y objects in a sorted list and store pointers to them in the X object. Sounds like it would perform the same.